# Need help finishing this Python code

Tags: python

I need help with my first code exercise. As you can see I made a list that contains strings
that prints out a specific text and i defined a function as. My intention is to make my function relate to my list somehow, and I don't know the next step. All suggestions would help. Thank you

```
code_me = ['java','css', 'python','html']
for x in code_me:
    if x =='java':
        print "this is java"
    elif x == 'css':
        print "this is css"
    elif x == 'python':
        print 'this is python'
    elif x == 'html':
        print 'this is html'

def code_func(x):
```

Comment: why do you have `def code_func(x)` at the end?

Answer (score 3):

You need `def` at the top if you want to make it a function

```
def code_func(code_me):
  for x in code_me:
     if x =='java':
        print "this is java"
     elif x == 'css':
         print "this is css"
     elif x == 'python':
         print 'this is python'
     elif x == 'html':
        print 'this is html'
```

Now you want to call the function with the list that you supplied

```
code_me = ['java','css', 'python','html']
code_func(code_me)
```

Comment: I... am not sure if that's what OP was asking, though to be fair it could be anything.

Comment: Yeah I just took a crack at it. I just assumed because of that random function call at the end. :D

Comment: @user144422 Click the check mark below the updown arrow if thats what you were looking for

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to correlate some action to a set of strings, the standard data structure would be a dictionary, not a list. Not going to spoon-feed the answer, but the example below should help you figure this out on your own:

```
lang_dict = {'java': 'this is java', 'css': 'this is css'}
def code_func(lang):
    print lang_dict[lang]

code_func('java') # 'this is java'
```

There are, to be fair, a number of fishy code practices in here, and this code would never go to production, but I hope that this helps you learn a little bit more about python as a whole.

Comment: Could even be cheeky and make `code_func = lang_dict.__getitem__` then print the result :p +1 for the correct suggestion of using a `dict` though

Comment: assuming that printing is the only action wanted and that the print statement wasn't just a placeholder for a more complicated action.